# UE4 Google admob ads not loading, even though everything is set up as described

Tags: android, admob, ads, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I know that many people already had this problem before, but i still don't have a solution.
My problem is that i want to show ads in my game, but even though i set everything up correctly (the APIs, everything on my google play console page, my ue4 project settings), it is still not working. I am using blueprints, and i already tried banner and interstitial ads. While the banner just doesn't show up, trying to load the interstitial throws the error "Interstitial Ad failed to load, errorcode: 1", which causes to app to crash. I already tried everything as described in this (pretty long) tutorial:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/61170-integrate-google-play-services-with-blueprint?89563-Integrate-Google-Play-Services-with-Blueprint=

I'll also attach my HUD blueprints:
[banner setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOpjI.png)
[interstitial setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlMV5.png)*

*the ShowAd event is called in a player pawn object, which also checks whether the interstitial is loaded or not, and if so, shows it before another level loads, for example.